# Burning multiple CDs simultaneously

Tags: burning, compact-disc

I want to burn multiple CDs at the same time, but I don't want to pay the big bucks for a replicator. Can I hook up multiple sata cd burners, and burn multiple CDs that way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Yes

Typical burning software on most platforms support selecting the "dvd writer" by name and burning a disc so the answer is.

On Windows I'm aware of this list of software having this feature, and most of these apps will let you have multiple instances of them open. I'm sure it will be similar on Linux and MAC OS applications.

- [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/)
- [Nero Burning Rom](http://www.nero.com/)
- [Magic ISO burner](http://www.magiciso.com/)

Just be careful of the system being under load, and it being able to handle supplying the data to that many sequential dvd writers.